# net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID Amplify + Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-amplify, amazon-elb

I have the following configuration:
On amplify, I have a react app hosted
On elastic beanstalk, I have a .NET Core 6 app hosted.

I have an application load balancer, with a ACM cert, with a 443 listen that forwards the traffic to the EC2 instance on port 80

I can confirm the EB side of everything works because I am able to postman my API end points.

The issue comes in, when I try to fire an API call from my front end via a button click. I get this error net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

In my route 53, I have a custom domain. Under my hosted zone, I have the A name pointing to my elastic load balancer, I have a CNAME pointing to my elastic load balancer, I have SSL ACM certs for both mysite.com and [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com).

I also confirmed with an AWS rep, that he was able to reach my EB on his end, with or without SSL, so both worked.

Someone please help me, its driving me nuts.